# Rolling two fair dices $A$ and $B$ and counting the number of odds where $B$ is rolled once more than $A$

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose $A$ and $B$ each roll a fair six sided dice $101$, $100$ times respectively. If we count the number of odds and evens in each sequence, what is the probability that $A$ has more number of odds than $B$ does?

I think the probability is $1/2$ if we roll both $A$ and $B$ the same number of times. But how does the probability change if we roll $A$ one more time?

Comment: On the contrary, with $A$ and $B$ rolling the same number of times, $A$ having strictly more odds than $B$, $A$ having strictly less odds than $B$ (*i.e. $A$ having strictly more evens than $B$*), and $A$ having the same number of odds as $B$ are all possible.  The first two cases by symmetry must be equally likely and the third case occurs with nonzero probability... so you should see the probability in the case $A$ and $B$ are rolling same amount of dice is in fact strictly *less* than $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: What can you say about the probability and cumulative distribution of the number of odds when a single person rolls the dice $N$ times? Now, how to combine these distributions of A and B to get your answer? Hint: I asked for the probability _and_ the cumulative distribution...